# How do I change the function that the button has to a different one?

Tags: android, function, button, integer

So we are working on a quiz game/app and we have a problem with just one thing. 
We got 4 buttons for the possible answers and only one of them is the correct one (obviusly). They are regular buttons with text on them, not the radio ones. The thing is that in order to avoid creating an activity for each question we wanna keep the buttons in one activity, and when pressed on the "correct answer" to change the buttons functions to be different. For example buttons 1,2,3 all send the player to gave over screen, while button 4 is the correct one. Then it should change the text that is displayed on the buttons and change all the buttons' functions so that 1,3,4 are now the "game over buttons" and 2 is the correct one. We tried if statements and integers, and booleans, to no avail. Any hints or solutions that could help us?
Thanks

Comment: Hey Konrol. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend sharing your code, and what effort you have invested so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and include relevant source code.

Answer (score 1):

Given your current setup I'd have each button's onClick call a method like `validateCorrectAnswer(int buttonNumber)` and then from there you'd do your validations. So for button1 you'd call `validateCorrectAnswer(1)`.

From `validateCorrectAnswer(...)` you'd have an array of correct answers, so it could be something like `int[] correctAnswers = {4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, ...};` and depending on which question they are on you'd check. So let's say you are on question 3 you'd check `correctAnswers[2] == buttonNumber`.

So to simplify that further within your activity store what question they are currently on in a global variable, something like `private int currentQuestion = 0` and then after each question you increment that number.

So the final method would be something like:

```
void validateCorrectAnswer(int buttonNumber) {
     if (correctAnswer[currentQuestion] == buttonNumber) {
         currentQuestion++;
         // correct answer, cool move on
     } else {
         // wrong answer, game over
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question class, you can set the answer to a text / button id and check on a button click if the button text / id is the same as your answer.

Also, see this example from butterknife:

```
//Specify multiple IDs in a single binding for common event handling.

@OnClick({ R.id.door1, R.id.door2, R.id.door3 })
public void pickDoor(DoorView door) {
  if (door.hasPrizeBehind()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You win!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Try again", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

source: [Butterknife docs](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **setTag(tagValue)** and **getTag(tagValue)** methods for the 4 buttons.

1 - correct

0 - wrong

And then just switch the tagValues according to the answer given.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int answer = 0;

    if(view instanceof Button) {
        answer = (int) ((Button)view).getTag();
    }

    if(answer == 1) {
        //true answer
        refreshButtons();
    } else {
        //game over
    }

    Log.d("TAG", "a: "+answer);

}

public void refreshButtons () {
    questionNr ++;
    Log.d("TAG", "q: "+questionNr);
    setAnswers(questionNr);
}

public void setAnswers (int question) {
    switch (question){
        case 1: // Second question
            v1.setTag(0);//wrong
            v2.setTag(1);//correct
            v3.setTag(0);//wrong
            v4.setTag(0);//wrong
            break;

        case 2:// Third question
            v1.setTag(0);//wrong
            v2.setTag(0);//wrong
            v3.setTag(1);//correct
            v4.setTag(0);//wrong
            break;

        case 3:// Forth question
            v1.setTag(0);//wrong
            v2.setTag(0);//wrong
            v3.setTag(0);//wrong
            v4.setTag(1);//correct
            break;
    }
}
```

You could also setup the texts for the other views in the same *setAnswer()* Method

The onCreate() method could be something like this :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//here you setup the answers for the first question
v1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
v1.setOnClickListener(this);
v1.setTag(1);

v2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
v2.setOnClickListener(this);
v2.setTag(0);

v3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
v3.setOnClickListener(this);
v3.setTag(0);

v4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
v4.setOnClickListener(this);
v4.setTag(0);
```